# Ubuntu upstart: Why does restart do the same thing as stop?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

This is my upstart file `/etc/init/myapp.conf`:

```
description "Example of starting Node with Upstart and Forever"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

expect fork

console output

setuid lwood

env HOME=/home/lwood

script
  cd $HOME
  exec forever -a -l /home/lwood/myapp/applog.log \
       start /home/lwood/myapp/app.js
end script

pre-stop script
  cd $HOME
  exec forever stop /home/lwood/myapp/app.js
end script
```

Do you know why `$ sudo restart myapp` is only stopping the service? It does not start the service after stopping it. So it has the same effect as `$ sudo stop myapp`.

Doing `$ sudo stop myapp` and then `$ sudo start myapp` works fine though. Wondering why restarting behaves different.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's something to do with the output of the script causing the upstart script to stop.

If you follow the guide on [this page](https://www.exratione.com/2013/02/nodejs-and-forever-as-a-service-simple-upstart-and-init-scripts-for-ubuntu/) they seem to recommend piping the stdout to a log file.

```
env LOG="/var/log/my-application.log"
exec forever stop /home/lwood/myapp/app.js >> $LOG
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it didn't work. Do you have any other ideas?